# How to parse through data efficiently

Tags: c#, algorithm

I am wondering if anyone can help me out with parsing out data for key words.

say I am looking for this keyword: `My Example Yo` (this is one of many keywords)

I have data like this

```
MY EXAMPLE YO #108
my-example-yo #108 
my-example #108 
MY Example #108
```

This is just a few combinations. There could be words or number is front of these sentences, there could be in any case, maybe nothing comes after it maybe like the above example something comes after it.

A few ideas came to mind.

1. store all combinations that I can possible think of in my database then use contains

The downside with this is I going a huge database table with every combination of everything thing I need to find. I then will have to load the data into memory(through nhibernate and check every combination). I am trying to determine what category to use based on keyword and they can upload thousands of rows to check for.

Even if I load subsets and look through them I still picture this will be slow.

1. Remove all special characters and make single spaces and ignore case and try to use regex to see how much of the keyword matches up.

Not sure what to do if the keyword has special characters like dashes and such.

I know I will not get every combination out there but I want to try get as many as I can.

Comment: How is the data you are parsing stored?  Is it stored in a flat file, a database, some structure in a C# app, or something else?

Comment: The data I am storing is coming from a csv file that later gets converted into a datatable through filehelper. I then check to see if one column I expect is missing. I then try to find a potential column that can get me this information(from the files I seen this is usually a description field) and that is what I am trying parse. The keywords will be in a mssql database that will be gotten by nhibernate.

Comment: @chobo2 You can use 'grep' utility for this.

Comment: @chobo2 It is a unix command-line utility. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grep . Command "grep -i 'my.example.yo' filename" should give you all the lines that contains pattern you are looking for.

Comment: I am using .net that will be consuming a file. Can I use grep (thought that was more command line for like linux)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered [Lucene.Net](http://incubator.apache.org/lucene.net/)? I haven't used it myself, but I hear it's a great tool for full text searching. It might do well with keyword searching too. I believe that [stackoverflow uses Lucene](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/stack-overflow-search-now-81-less-crappy/).

Comment: I will look into it. I am wondering though it seems to use indexes. The table with the keywords will probably be guid and varchar() will a index help on this? I am don't use indexes too much so don't know much about them.